# how to add data-role=page like jquery mobile in materialize?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

I have a developed a sample app using cordova, In that I'm using materialize css and jquery2.1. I tried to add pages like jquery mobile. When I add jquery mobile the css is getting conflicted. How to handle this and add pages using materialize css. I got materialize css and js from [here](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html)

Comment: Check the order of style sheet first materialize, then jquery mobile css and then your style sheet

Comment: Yeah! I tried it. But no use. @AtalShrivastava

Comment: Can you show your code or make a jsfiddle

Comment: here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dddb8kn/28/)

Comment: you need to overwrite the classes in css which creating conflict in your style.css. In this way you can achieve what you are looking for.